# How to save high resolution charts .png in Excel for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-office, charts, png

Is there any way to save a chart from excel to a high resolution png-file on office for Mac? I have tried to copy them into Word as well as saving them as a html-file, but the quality becomes really bad. Unfortunately it is not possible to use xtoolbox either as it only exists for Windows.

I would be very grateful for any help. It would also be very interesting if anyone had an explanation why Office does not create a built in tool like xtoolbox - I have tried it on windows and it's super convenient!

Thank you in advance,
Mikael

Comment: One way *may* be to save a PDF of the Excel chart and export said PDF as a PNG. This will probably only work if Excel writes charts in vector format when writing to PDF. Also, you may need Acrobat Pro to export as a PNG or some other image editing software that can rasterize the PDF at the desired resolution. Not posting as an answer as this is untested and I know know if it will actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is to save the plot as a file, and from there you can drag and drop the file into whichever application you want.

Here's an example procedure:

1. right-click the plot in Excel and in the Excel menu, choose Edit > Copy
2. open Preview app
3. in the Preview app menu options, choose File > New From Clipboard (now, you should see the plot open as a new file called "Untitled" in Preview)
4. in the Preview app menu options, choose File > Save, and in the resulting options under Format, choose "PNG", define a name for the file in the "Save As" text box and hit "Save"

Answer (score 1):

If you use a multi button mouse with your Mac, you can right click in the body of the chart and there is a "Save as image option", it will save as PNG format.
If you have the magic mouse, go to settings, mouse, and activate the secondary click option.